# writing a value in textbox stored in array

Tags: c#

My problem is, that I`m not able to write a value into a textbox object.
Here is the part of the code where the textboxes are created:

```
int number = 10;

TextBox[,] arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte= new TextBox[10,3];
for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{
    TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
    newTextBox.Location = new Point(0, (3+(i * 25)));
    newTextBox.Size = new Size(25, 26);
    newTextBox.Text = "H" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
    newTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
    panel1.Controls.Add(newTextBox);

    arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 0] = newTextBox;

    TextBox newTextBox2 = new TextBox();
    newTextBox2.Location = new Point(28, (3+(i * 25)));
    newTextBox2.Size = new Size(50, 26);
    newTextBox2.ReadOnly = true;
    panel1.Controls.Add(newTextBox2);

    arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 1] = newTextBox2;

    TextBox newTextBox3 = new TextBox();
    newTextBox3.Location = new Point(83, (3+(i * 25)));
    newTextBox3.Size = new Size(50, 26);
    newTextBox3.ReadOnly = true;
    panel1.Controls.Add(newTextBox3);

    arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 2] = newTextBox3;
}
```

Here is the method that should write values in the textboxes:

```
private void addHochpunkt(float xValue, float yValue)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i,1].Text)))
       {
         continue;
       }
       arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 1].Text = "xValue";
       arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 2].Text = "yValue";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change ``"xValue"`` to ``xValue.ToString()`` , as you want to convert it to string

Comment: Did you declare globally the array? Because the code above seems to use a local array of textboxes.

Comment: you are not using the values at all you are assigning everything the string value of `"xValue yValue"` you need to do the following 
`arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 1].Text = xValue.ToString();
 arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 2].Text = yValue.ToString();` you need to understand how to use conversion of values

Comment: Did you get any error message from your addHochpunkt method? If yes what?

Comment: @Steve Yes, the following: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred"

Comment: I declared the array globally and deleted the local declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared globally the array `TextBox[,] arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte` then you don't declare again locally an array with the same name. In that way you initialize the local one leaving the global empty triggering the famous NullReferenceException when you try to use the global one

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox[,] arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
         int number = 10;
         // This line declares an array with the same name and thus
         // hides the global one declared at the form/class level
         // All your initialization goes into this local one that is
         // lost when you exit from this method..... remove it...
         // TextBox[,] arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte= new TextBox[10,3];

         // This line initializes the global array so it is available 
         // also in other methods.....
         arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte= new TextBox[10,3];
         .....
         initialization code 
         .....

    }

    private void addHochpunkt(float xValue, float yValue)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           // Here you try to reference the global array, but
           // your current code leaves the global one without initialization
           // thus a NullReferenceException..... 
           if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i,1].Text)))
           {
             continue;
           }
           // I suppose that you want to write the value 
           // of the two variables not their names.
           arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 1].Text = xValue.ToString();
           arrayTextBoxenHochpunkte[i, 2].Text = yValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```